# How would I select the Server to run an ADSI command on?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Recently, I have been trying to set up a new user script using powershell. In doing this, I have been trying to have it set the tsprofiles using ADSI. When run by itself (after the user has been set up) it runs perfectly, however, when run in conjunction to a script, setting the profiles will fail. Below is the relevant part of the script

```
$DistinguishedName  = (Get-AdUser -Identity $UserName).DistinguishedName
$user = [ADSI] "LDAP://$distinguishedName"
$user.psbase.Invokeset("terminalservicesprofilepath","$tsProfilePath$username")
$user.psbase.Invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory","$homeDirectory$username")
$user.psbase.Invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDrive","$homeDirectoryDrive")
$user.setinfo()}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
One thought that I have had has been that it could be setting the server that ADSI runs on as we have multiple primary Domain Controllers.

Comment: What do you mean by conjunction of a script. Can you provide that example as well since that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Why ADSI, vs the AD cmdlets?

I am going to assume, that the response to the aforementioned, is that you do not have RSAT on your workstation. However, y[ou don't need to install that either. Just establish a remote session to any DC or another host that has RSAT enabled, and proxy the cmdlet to your workstation via explicit PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ashleymcglone/how-to-use-the-2012-active-directory-powershell-cmdlets-from-windows-7), which is a very common thing to do.

Anyway, dealing with MS Terminal Services via ADSI is not PowerShell specific and not anything new. There are years-old VBScript code samples, all over the web showing this exact use case, and thus the same thing can be done with any scripting. You'd make this setting at the domain level, and DC replication would take care of all else.

A search using your favorite engine with say '[powershell adsi connect to server](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20adsi%20connect%20to%20server&form=ANNTH1&refig=3ac511518de341318116be1456bc144f&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20adsi%20connect%20to%20serve&sc=1-32&qs=n&sk=&cvid=3ac511518de341318116be1456bc144f)' or ''powershell '[.psbase.Invokeset("terminalservicesprofilepath' adsi](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20%27.psbase.Invokeset(%22terminalservicesprofilepath%27%20adsi&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20%27.psbase.invokeset(%22terminalservicesprofilepath%27%20adsi&sc=0-65&sk=&cvid=DB28C414C7B3439787D43921A34BBEE6)' or '[adsi set terminalservicesprofilepath](https://www.bing.com/search?q=adsi%20set%20terminalservicesprofilepath&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=adsi%20set%20terminalservicesprofilepath&sc=0-36&sk=&cvid=B96F8C09900D4AFBA12D08654E24953C)' and will show you many examples:

```
# Connect to a domain
$domainname = "SomeDomainName" #or use $env:userdomain
[ADSI]$domain = "WinNT://$domainname"
```

Or leverage prebuilt stuff

[Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Edit Terminal Server Profiles for Users in Active Directory?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-edit-terminal-server-profiles-for-users-in-active-directory/)

```
# QueryAndModifyTerminalServerProperties.ps1

function SetTSProperties()
{
    $ou = [adsi]"LDAP://ou=mytestou,dc=nwtraders,dc=com"
    $user = $ou.psbase.get_children().find($userDN)
    $user.psbase.invokeSet("allowLogon", 1)
    $user.psbase.invokeSet("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory", $hDirValue)
    $user.psbase.invokeSet("TerminalServicesProfilePath", $ppValue)
    $user.psbase.invokeSet("TerminalServicesHomeDrive", $hdValue)
    $user.setinfo() 
} #end SetTSProperties

function QueryTSProperties()
{
    $ou = [adsi]"LDAP://ou=mytestou,dc=nwtraders,dc=com"
    $user = $ou.psbase.get_children().find($userDN)
    foreach ($property in $aryTSProperties)
    {
        "$($Property) value: $($user.psbase.invokeget($Property))"
    } #end foreach
} #end QueryTSProperties

$userDN = "CN=My User"
$hDirValue = "\\Hamburg\TSUsers\Home\TestUser"
$hdValue = "t:"
$ppValue = "\\Hamburg\TSUsers\Profiles\TestUser"
$aryTSProperties = "allowLogon", "TerminalServicesHomeDirectory",
"TerminalServicesHomeDrive", "TerminalServicesProfilePath"

SetTSProperties
queryTSProperties
```